angular-18 router-state navigation, state is undefined
I have an application that have in one of its components, a button that route to another component with a state to be consumed in the target component , the code for this is :
 <button *ngIf="types.includes(Type.A)"
                [routerLink]="'/' + IN_APP_ROUTES.prefix+ '/' + Id+ '/' +IN_APP_ROUTES.new"
                [state]="state"
                class="btn btn-link text-nowrap"
                
                type="button">Upload new
  </button>

then in the target component I got the state from :
history.state

it was working fine with angular 14 and 16 , then a couple of days ago the team has upgraded the application to angular 18 and then the state in the target component  stopped working , when i conosle.log it , it has navigationId 1 but do not have the object I set in the router-Link, while I was debugging I tried to subscribe to the router events in the taget component , and was able to find the state in the NavigationStart event ,
 this.router.events.pipe(
  filter(e => e instanceof NavigationStart),
  map(() => {
    const currentState = this.router.getCurrentNavigation();
    return currentState?.extras.state;
  })
).subscribe((res)=>{
  this.state = res as myObject|| this.state;
  console.log('at-subscribe', this.state);


});

but after this event the state is undefined again , can anyone please let me know how it should work now ?

In Angular, NavigationStart is an event triggered when the router starts the process of navigating to a different route. However, the NavigationStart event itself doesn't directly provide access to the state property (which is available in the NavigationEnd or NavigationExtras).
If you need to access the state during NavigationStart, you can retrieve the state object passed via Router.navigate() from history.state. Here's how you can do it:
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, NavigationStart } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  
  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
      if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
        const state = history.state; // Get the navigation state
        console.log('NavigationStart state:', state);
      }
    });
  }
}

history.state: This will give you the state object associated with the navigation. It works in NavigationStart because history.state holds the state of the current page (as provided by Router.navigate()).
If you are navigating with Router.navigate() and passing the state like:
this.router.navigate(['/some-route'], { state: { myData: 'test' } });

You can access it using history.state as shown above during the NavigationStart event.
In Angular 18, this.router.getCurrentNavigation() will return null in any lifecycle phase other than when the router is processing a navigation request (e.g., when the NavigationStart event is triggered). This is a known issue, and the router navigation state might not be accessible in the NavigationStart event.
To reliably get the state during navigation, it's better to use the history.state property instead, as it works well across Angular versions and does not depend on the navigation lifecycle phases.
this.router.events.pipe(
  filter(event => event instanceof NavigationStart),
  map(() => {
    // Use history.state to get the current state
    const currentState = history.state;
    return currentState;
  })
).subscribe((res) => {
  this.state = res as myObject || this.state;
  console.log('at-subscribe', this.state);
});


when I use history.state with the NavigationStart event  , the state is not retrieved , what i got is
{
"navigationId": 4
}

can you try the NavigationEnd instead of NavigationStart?

still the same it would get me a {"navigationId": 5} , a navigationId with a number I believe the state is being written over at some point in the router event

please check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-rqkeeq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcomponents%2Fmovie%2Fmovie.component.ts
check console
